# Magnolia Blossom example using Maven

Tags: spring-mvc, maven-3, magnolia

I am new in Magnolia. I want to integrate Magnolia with Spring. I have gone through Magnolia documentation, I have seen how Blossom is used to integrate with Spring.

I am not getting full example of Spring Blossom. Can anyone tell me how to create Magnolia Blossom project with Maven?

What is flow of Spring Blossom? How does Spring Blossom work with front end technologies?

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation of the module contains what you are looking for,
please have a look at: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Blossom+module

Cheers,